# Linking error Google Colab with Google Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am trying to connect to Google Drive from Collaborator. I linked the Drive and it gives me a

```
Connection to Google drive successful message.
```

Though, when I try to access the 'Dataset' folder, it throwns me a

```
ls: cannot access '/mydrive/Sources/Dataset/': No such file or directory
```

The code is as below.

```
# Check is Link to Drive is OK
google = !if [ -d 'mydrive/' ]; then echo "1" ; else echo "0"; fi
if (google[0] is '0' ):
  from google.colab import drive
  drive.mount('/content/mydrive')
!if [ -d 'mydrive/' ]; then echo "Connection to Google drive successful" ; else echo "Error to connect to Google drive"; fi
!ls "/mydrive/Sources/Dataset/"
```

Please help.

Comment: show your code as text

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited the question.

Comment: There are at least two bugs in the pasted code:
- the mount is at /content/mydrive but the last line refers to /mydrive/... (missing the leading /content/)
- /content/mydrive will a "My Drive" subdirectory, so the last line probably wants to be something like 
  `!ls "/content/mydrive/My Drive/Sources/Dataset/"`
  (in case that still doesn't work for you, you might enjoy the file browser in the left-hand panel, which you can use to navigate the /content directory to see what's where)

Comment: Thank you! This worked! It would be helpful if you could post this as an answer.

Comment: Done (originally posted as comment instead of answer as question was locked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two bugs in the pasted code:

- the mount is at /content/mydrive but the last line refers to /mydrive/... (missing the leading /content/)
- /content/mydrive will have a "My Drive" subdirectory, so the last line probably wants to be something like `!ls "/content/mydrive/My Drive/Sources/Dataset/"`

In case that still doesn't work for you, you might enjoy the file browser in the left-hand panel, which you can use to navigate the /content directory to see what's where.

(promoted comment to answer now that question is unlocked)